# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable, in a HTML

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I am new to coding and I learning about web scrapping using beautiful soup.
I try to extract out a None Type from a HTML file but I dont get it how to solve this problem
Also there is a list that I want to extract from the HTML that start from 1 to 450, how do I assign the list value to the coding?

Here is my coding:

Result_1 = soup.find("div", class_="row search-results d-flex flex-column tablescraper-selected-table")

storeListings = Result_1.find_all("div", class_="item-deets d-flex flex-column")

for store in storeListings:

for a in range (1,301):

dataset_ = []

name = store.find("input", id = "hidden_title"{a})["value"]

print (name)

Example of HTML

div class="item-deets d-flex flex-column"

input type="hidden" id="hidden_title341" value="Uptown Parade"

I expected to extract the name that contains the Uptown Parade

Answer (score 0):

This error is being caused because your web scraper is finding no data in the HTML element you are trying to get data from. An easy workaround for this is to simply put an if statement in your code

```
"if name is not None:"
```

before you make your code try to do anything. This could either be caused because your selector is not accurately getting the data out, or it could be caused by the page you are scraping simply not having the data your scraper is looking for. I would recommend starting the scraper out with just one page, and seeing if it works for that page. If it still returns none, then your problem is probably with your code. If it works and you get the name, then you need to just work around the errors by checking if the type is none first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).